# Issue in Connecting CosmosDB using Germlin Graph PHP

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect cosmos azure db with Gremlin graph php I have enter all the details correctly but still facing the issue.

Here is exact error that I am facing:

Welcome to Azure Cosmos DB + Gremlin on PHP!

Attempting to connect...

Caught exception:
gremlin-php driver has thrown the following error :

PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught Brightzone\GremlinDriver\InternalException: gremlin-php driver has thrown the following error : Could not write to socket in E:\germl
in\azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started\vendor\brightzone\gremlin-php\src\C
onnection.php:791

Stack trace:

## 0 E:\germlin\azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started\vendor\brightzone\gremlin-php\src\Connection.php(523):Brightzone\GremlinDriver\Connection->error('Could not write...', 500, true)

## 1 E:\germlin\azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started\vendor\brightzone\gremlin-php\src\Connection.php(657):Brightzone\GremlinDriver\Connection->close()

## 2 [internal function]: Brightzone\GremlinDriver\Connection->__destruct()

## 3 {main}

thrown in E:\germlin\azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started\vendor\brightzone\gremlin-php\src\Connection.php on line 791

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What mode are you using to connect? Gateway? Direct TCP? Regardless of what it is, check which port you need to have open and see if that port is available/open (and open it if you are an admin)

Comment: Hello, can you share the code where you're initializing the connection object? My guess is that it might be missing the `ssl => TRUE` parameter. See this sample for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-php

Comment: Specifically, look at the way the Connection object is created here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started/blob/master/connect.php

Comment: SSL is True in my connection file..@LuisBosquez

Comment: Port was 443 and I checked, it was not there so I did open it but still no solution..@JoshuaKrstic

Comment: @RahulThakral What is the the format of the gremlin endpoint you are connecting to? The one in the php sample is out-of-date and should be <account-name>.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com.

Comment: @OliverTowers I got the issue.. It was timeout issue which is by default 0.5 in connet.php of source code.. 
$db->timeout = 3.5; 

Thanks Everyone for your efforts..